# How to automatically change drawables depending on a flavor?

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

I'm working on a really messy app and first time with flavors. App has like 4,5 flavors all with identical background colors, drawables, etc. Only logo is different.

Now I have to make a new flavor with completely different layout. Background color should be yellow instead of grey and drawable images should be black instead of white. The problem is, I have like 100 different white images. Is there a way I can change them to black automatically? (designer can redraw them or whatever to be black and I can put them in drawable folder of that flavor) Or I would have to programmatically check if new flavor is used then call setDrawable(newBlackImage) on every widget that uses white drawable?  That seems like a very complicated way to do since all drawables are set via XML layout..

The way they've been using flavors was creating resource bool file and then check in code if some key has value true/false then hide/show some things... So I assume I should do something similar with this, or no?

This is what the project structure for one of my flavors looks like:

[image]

As you can see, every flavor only has different launcher and login screen icons. Also each has their own arrays, bools and strings resource files. But all of them share same layout resources and drawables with white icons.

Comment: If you use VectorDrawables instead of image resources, they can be tinted programmatically without using different files.

Comment: Unfortunately all of them are image resources :/ Designer told me he can send me the black ones so it's not a problem. Main problem is, I have a layout that sets the src for imageview as one of white icons. I just want to avoid changing it to black ones programmatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're already in the right way. By creating specific flavours for each group of drawable in your gradle file you'll just need to create a drawable folder for the flavours with specific files.

For example, the flavour 'black' will need a drawable folder in which all your black-background images will be stored.

In order to get it working, all resources must exist for all flavours so you won't need to change any part of your code.

You can find a quick guide here:
https://medium.com/@thiagolopessilva/the-handling-multiple-java-source-and-resources-using-flavors-on-gradle-18a4b581285b

Comment: That's a great article, tnx man! Now I understand it better so I updated my question so you can see if my project structure is wrong. Maybe the problem is that all my white icons are inside main drawable folder and all of layouts are inside main layout folder.. each flavor only has different launcher icon. So if I change something in one layout, all of flavors will have that change. If I understood you right, this flavor structure I showed you above, should have drawable folder with black icons, right? But then it would also need to have all the layouts in order to assign those icons?

Comment: Maybe since all of flavors are using same layouts, I can create put all the black icons inside of this flavor drawable folder and name them the same as white? So layout will have ImageView with android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" field, so if my flavor has ic_add_white_24dp inside of it's drawable (but it will be black) it will use that one..

Comment: That's correct. Resources in `main` are your baseline, any resources in the flavor folders with the same path/name will override them in the app.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but you got it right.